# Angular material datepicker: how to get two distinct validation errors for invalid and required input

Tags: angular, validation, angular-material, angular2-formbuilder

I want to validate an angular material datepicker input against empty value and against invalid date format but with having two separate error messages, one in case of empty value and the other in case of invalid input.

My html:

```
     <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Data di nascita*</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
           formControlName="birthday">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker- 
         toggle>
        <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error 
           *ngIf="newCat.controls['birthday'].hasError('required')">Campo 
             obbligatorio</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="newCat.controls['birthday'].invalid">Formato di 
            data errato</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>
```

My ts:

```
    this.newCat = this.formBuilder.group({
       name: ['', Validators.required],
       birthday: ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

In my case compares two messages together when the input is emty or when the date is not valid, I obtain "Campo obbligatorio" and "Formato di data errato" both together.

Comment: Set it to readonly and use proper format for your date picker selection!

Comment: I need to have the field editable

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
        <mat-label>Data di nascita*</mat-label>
        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" 
           formControlName="birthday" [matDatepickerFilter]="filterDatePicker()">
        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker- 
         toggle>
        <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
        <mat-error 
           *ngIf="newCat.controls['birthday'].hasError('required')">Campo 
             obbligatorio</mat-error>
        <mat-error *ngIf="invalidDate">Formato di 
            data errato</mat-error>
     </mat-form-field>


filterDatePicker() {
 // write your logic for selected date validation here.
   if(uoir condition) {

   this.invalidDate = true;

} else {
 this.invalidDate = false;
}
```

Comment: Probably this is the only possible solution

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1.
Set matinput for Datepicker to readonly, and then set the valid Date format for DatePicker in TS or HTML code:

```
<input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="birthday" readonly>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<mat-datepicker touchUi #picker></mat-datepicker>
```

2.
Change your second Mat-Error tag to:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="!newCat.controls['birthday'].hasError('required') && newCat.controls['birthday'].invalid">
  Formato di data errato
</mat-error>
```

Comment: The first option is not applicable because I want to have the input editable. The secondo option doesn't work.